# Conditional distribution of minimum of shifted exponential sample, given its mean

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Consider a random sample of size $n$ from a two-parameter exponential distribution, $X_i\sim EXP(\theta, \eta)$.

In other words, the density function of $X_i$ is given by:

$$f_X(x;\theta,\eta)=\frac{e^{-(x-\eta)/\theta}}{\theta}~\mathbf 1_{x\gt \eta, \theta>0}$$

Let $\bar X$ be the sample mean and let $X_{(1)}$ be the minimum order statistic.

Show that the conditional pdf of $X_{(1)}$ given $\bar X$ does not depend on $\theta$.

Since I don't know either conditional distribution or the joint distribution, I don't understand how I'm supposed to calculate this PDF.  Can someone please help?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean gamma distribution?

Comment: Without information regarding the density function for a single observation, it is not possible to answer your question.

Comment: The density function is given here: https://prnt.sc/imywq1
I edited the question.

Comment: Maybe some argument involving ancillarity would work.